# how to plot in bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh, runumap

Hi there I'm quite new to Python plotting in general but somehow I can get the gist of things from examples; however, I couldn't find anything useful/helpful to understand how to use `bokeh` to plot a UMAP.

After experimenting with some tutorial all I get is a single dot, whereas I should have a UMAP based on the NumPy array I'm using. *See* below for an example

**umap_proj**

```
array([[  9.467572  ,   1.3644829 ],
       [  9.608901  ,   1.2682369 ],
       [  0.2737476 ,   6.213452  ],
       [  3.2541463 ,  10.000814  ],
       [ 23.634834  ,   3.198842  ],
       [ 23.586329  ,   3.2471323 ],
       [  3.6388707 ,   5.290971  ],
       [  0.07268663,   5.7849684 ],
       [  0.20859158,   5.7292304 ],
       [  0.84385896,   5.0269856 ],
       [ 11.656524  ,  15.852114  ],
       [ 11.690001  ,  15.9092865 ],
       [  4.307997  ,   9.4132395 ],
       [  4.315025  ,   9.4042425 ],
       [  4.57423   ,  12.418981  ],
       [  4.3381214 ,  13.442026  ],
       [  9.221395  ,   0.99569064],
       [  9.417851  ,   1.2935886 ],
       [  4.0001864 ,  14.564397  ],
       [  9.4523325 ,   2.5142562 ],
       [  0.18032   ,   5.607879  ],
       [  0.20974386,   5.5906544 ],
       [  8.327373  , -13.634082  ],
       [  4.436351  ,  14.6661625 ],
       [  4.439193  ,  14.614582  ],
...
       [  8.337706  , -13.553178  ],
       [  4.1751633 ,   5.5536766 ],
       [  4.110508  ,   5.5729456 ],
       [ 14.518264  ,   7.623279  ],
       [  9.572984  , -13.1281595 ]], dtype=float32)
```

This is how my array looks like, but I really cannot figure out how to specify to Python to use it for plotting using the `figure` and `circles` functions of `bokeh`. Here the libraries I'm importing:

**EDIT TO SHOW ALL COMMANDS**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import bokeh.plotting as bp

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from umap import UMAP

umap = pd.read_csv("SGDP_bi_snps_norm-2.eigenvec", sep="\t")
umap.rename(columns={"#IID": "#ID"}, inplace=True)

loc = pd.read_csv("loc_fix_python-order.txt")

eigenval = pd.read_csv("SGDP_bi_snps_norm-2.eigenval", header=None)
pve = round(eigenval / (eigenval.sum(axis=0))*100, 2)
pve.head()

umap.sort_values('#ID', inplace=True)
umap.insert(loc=1, column='#LOC', value=loc)
umap.rename(columns={'#ID': 'ID', '#LOC': 'LOC'}, inplace=True)

regions_umap = umap.iloc[:, 2:12]

umap_plot = UMAP(n_components=2, init="random", random_state=15)
umap_proj = umap_plot.fit_transform(regions_umap)
umap_proj.view()

fig = figure(title='SGDP UMAP')
fig.circle(umap_proj[1], umap_proj[2])
```

Any input on how to start is much appreciated, and sorry for the basic question but I cannot figure it out!

P.S. in `plotly` works just fine

Comment: To get a response I think you'd need to post the code you've been trying that doesn't work; otherwise the answer is just to follow an example like https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/examples/basic/scatters/color_scatter.html .

Comment: @JamesA.Bednar Indeed, I'm editing the main text to show what I tried.

Comment: Hi Matteo. To display your figure, you need to call `show(fig)`. FYI: The recommended function to plot many circles is [`fig.scatter()`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting/figure.html#bokeh.plotting.figure.scatter). I hope this [example from the docs](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/examples/basic/scatters/color_scatter.html) will help you.

Comment: @mosc9575 I see, but all I get is a plot with two points in it... is there anything wrong in how I use my NumPy array with `bokeh`? I switched to `fig.scatter()` but the outcome is the same. I think there is something wrong in how I use/run `bokeh` plotting, but I don't understand what it is...

Comment: @JamesA.Bednar I figure out the problem was that I wasn't selecting columns appropriately for `bokeh to plot. Also, when I wrote the meaning of `ColumnDataFrame`, and `source` in the scatter function, were not very clear yet

Comment: In don't know the type of your `umap_proj` but if this is an array, you did pass the single values using `umap_proj[1]` and `umap_proj[2]` and not a array. If you write `fig.scatter([1,2,3], [1,2,3])` you will see 3 circles.